Multitasking Controls button is missing for my app in iPad
I am making my iPhone app to support iPad .
But after running in Xcode 's iPad simulator , I found that the Multitasking Controls button (three dot button) is missing in my app's statue bar ,

but exist in other apps (eg : Files app)

Is there any develop configuration for this button 's hide&show in specific app
I have remove UIRequiresFullScreen key in the info.plist already . any other option to toggle this button ?

OK I got the key to this problem to show the button you need do two steps:

your iPad app should support all orientations(portrait and landscape)
set UIRequiresFullScreen to YES

as official doc says in here
